# Laravel token missmatch exception

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, crop

I am trying to upload image by ajax. I am using [Croppic Master](http://www.croppic.net/) but when I upload the image, it gives me **token miss match exception**. How to pass token in the below code?

```
<div class="col-lg-4 ">
  <div id="cropContaineroutput">
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="cropOutput" style="width:100%; padding:5px 4%; margin:20px auto; display:block; border: 1px solid #CCC;" />
```

**JS**

```
    var croppicContaineroutputOptions = {
    uploadUrl: '<?php echo url()?>/users/cover',
    cropUrl: 'img_crop_to_file.php',
    outputUrlId: 'cropOutput',
    modal: false,
    loaderHtml: '<div class="loader bubblingG"><span id="bubblingG_1"></span><span id="bubblingG_2"></span><span id="bubblingG_3"></span></div> ',
    onBeforeImgUpload: function () {
        console.log('onBeforeImgUpload')
    },
    onAfterImgUpload: function () {
        console.log('onAfterImgUpload')
    },
    onImgDrag: function () {
        console.log('onImgDrag')
    },
    onImgZoom: function () {
        console.log('onImgZoom')
    },
    onBeforeImgCrop: function () {
        console.log('onBeforeImgCrop')
    },
    onAfterImgCrop: function () {
        console.log('onAfterImgCrop')
    },
    onReset: function () {
        console.log('onReset')
    },
    onError: function (errormessage) {
        console.log('onError:' + errormessage)
    }
}
var cropContaineroutput = new Croppic('cropContaineroutput', croppicContaineroutputOptions);
```

Comment: try adding this in form `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` or add this to your main layout `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877117/laravel-csrf-token

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with ajax request and the trick bellow solved the problem.

Add the token in your template:

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Then in your javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to include the token into your AJAX calls:

```
/** inside your blade **
<script> 
var token = '{{csrf_token()}}'
$.ajax('url/to/api', { 
     ....
     data: { 
           ....
           '_token' : token
        } 
 }
</script>
```

Essentially, as long as your request has the CSRF token within a field called `_token`it should work.