# Laravel CSRF protection

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, token, csrf

I know what CSRF attack is, and I have read the documentation about it, however I have trouble understanding how CSRF protection works in depth, and have some general questions I couldn't find.

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf) it says that Laravel automatically generates a token for

> ... each active user session managed by the application.

1. Where does it create the token (what part of the code triggers it)?
2. Where is the token stored after creation, in cookie? In session? How can I extract and see what has been stored? Is this all actually controlled by `session.php`?
3. What does this mean when I reload the page, is the token still the same as the `session.php` has 120 min default lifetime?
4. What happens with that cookie when I navigate to subdomain handled by the same app if I have set my `domain` property to be `"." . env('APP_URL')`?

So once the token has been created and stored somewhere, when making a request, I have to provide either `csrf_token()` hidden property to the form, or generate it as a meta field and redirect to my JS file if I'm doing an AJAX request.

5. So what happens in low-level when I actually make a request? Request generates `csrf_token()`, Laravel encrypts the cookie, Laravel checks if the cookie sent is the same as the cookie in session. If yes, it means that the request is valid, if not, throw `TokenMissmatchException`?
6. Does that mean that every request during the lifetime of the cookie will have the same token?
7. Does Laravel encrypt request and response cookies differently? If I exclude token from cookie encryption in `EncryptCookies` class I get the same token, but when I leave it, hashes are different.
8. How does providing `_token` in the request data differ from forwarding token as `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header? How does Laravel validate those if I see them unencrypted? Do they get encrypted after the request?

Comment: There are a lot of different questions here, which doesn't work well with the format of this site: while it would be possible for an answer to cover them all, it would be easy to end up with multiple answers each covering different aspects, or the page devolving into discussions and amendments. It would be better if you could focus the question down a bit, and possibly raise multiple questions if necessary.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you for internal logic for csrf https://stackoverflow.com/a/51673924/4701635

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Where does it create the token (what part of the code triggers it)?

After going through the helpers file

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
```

which had the definition of `csrf_token()` helper method, which calls the token method on

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php
```

and if you check the `start()` which calls `regenerateToken()` if `_token` hasn't been set, it save a random 40 character string to the session with the key of `_token`

```
/**
 * Regenerate the CSRF token value.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function regenerateToken()
{
    $this->put('_token', Str::random(40));
}
```

> 2. Where is the token stored after creation, in cookie? In session? How can I extract and see what has been stored? Is this all actually controlled by session.php?

The token is stored in session, you can extract it using `session('_token')`. The session expiration time is controlled in `session.php` using

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

> 3. What does this mean when I reload the page, is the token still the same as the session.php has 120 min default lifetime?

If you check `start()` in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php`

```
/**
 * Start the session, reading the data from a handler.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function start()
{
    $this->loadSession();

    if (! $this->has('_token')) {
        $this->regenerateToken();
    }

    return $this->started = true;
}
```

the token is regenerated if the session does not have `_token`. So `_token` would be same until the session expires

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing APP_URL=http://localhost from .env solved problems with CSRF token. I do not configure fixed value in APP_URL for local dev because I use always different hostnames via browser and sometimes ports.